# Using MVVM Pattern for App with Login Authentication in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and the Model-View-ViewModel Pattern and not sure about when to use it.

I'm developing an application in which Users will have to log in with a username and a password. When logged in, I want to display different properties assigned to these users, like Name, Avatar/Picture, Balance etc.
I plan to update those user objects once every 15 mins or even less frequently.

Now I'm not sure if the MVVM pattern is fitting here, because it is often referenced in connection with very complex UIs. I only need to display 5 basic properties of a single user. Is it even worth going for MVVM here?

Comment: I would say yes because mvvm helps with data binding which is a very powerful tool in updating the UI. Since you're updating the UI throughout the app lifetime, databinding will help do all the legwork without you having to write custom update logic. Also, you'll find that it'll be easier for your app to grow with the mvvm structure.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern is most benefic when you to write unit-test of the logic (Model and ViewModel) of your application. Some other avantages of MVVM are that your code is better organized and you can easily reuse differents components. This make sence for complex applications but for small application this is not really benefic. And according to your description you are writing a small one